# Why can't I access the private constructor in my static function as below?

Tags: c++

I'm currently write a weak reference resource manager as below, and the compiler complained Manager has a private constructor.

My question is that: why can't I access the private member function in the static function?

```cpp
#ifndef TENSOR_MANAGER_H
#define TENSOR_MANAGER_H

#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

template<typename key_t, typename model_t>
class Manager : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Manager<key_t, model_t> > {
public:
    using self_t = Manager<key_t, model_t>;

public:
    static auto Create() {
        return std::make_shared<self_t>();
    }

public:

    std::shared_ptr<model_t> GetOrAdd(const key_t &&key, const char *data, size_t size) {
        auto pos = m_resources.find(key);
        std::shared_ptr<model_t> tmp;
        if (pos != m_resources.end()) {
            tmp = pos->second.lock();
        }
        if (!tmp) {
            model_t *p = new model_t();

            auto deletor = std::bind(&self_t::releaseItem,
                                     std::weak_ptr<self_t>(this->shared_from_this()),
                                     key,
                                     std::placeholders::_1);

            tmp = std::shared_ptr<model_t>(p, deletor);

            m_resources[key] = std::weak_ptr<model_t>(tmp);
        }
        return tmp;
    }

public:
    void Print() {
        std::cout << "Content: ";
        for (const auto &item : m_resources) {
            std::cout << item.first << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

private:
    static void releaseItem(std::weak_ptr<self_t> self, const key_t &key, model_t *p) {
        std::shared_ptr<Manager<key_t, model_t>> mgr = self.lock();
        if (mgr) {
            mgr->m_resources.erase(key);
        }
        delete p;
    }

private:
    std::map<key_t, std::weak_ptr<model_t> > m_resources;

    Manager() = default;
};

#endif //TENSOR_MANAGER_H
```

Now the compiler gives the errors:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:2043:66: error: field of type 'Manager<std::__1::basic_string<char>, int>' has private default constructor
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY constexpr __compressed_pair_elem() : __value_() {}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147027/how-do-i-call-stdmake-shared-on-a-class-with-only-protected-or-private-const

Answer (score 15):

As per Cppreference, the notes on [**`make_shared`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) clearly state that:

> `std::shared_ptr<T>(new T(args...))` may call a non-public constructor of `T` if executed in context where it is accessible, while **`std::make_shared`** requires ***public access*** to the selected constructor.

Since the selected constructor in this case is `private`, compilation fails.
If you still wish to keep it `private` use the form `std::shared_ptr<T>(new T(args...))` in the `static` function `Create`.

**EDIT:**
If you are intent on using `make_shared` and also a `private` constructor, you can employ this hack which uses an empty nested `class` and an `explicit` constructor.

A minimal example.

```
#include <memory>

class Bar : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Bar> 
{

private:
    class Foo {};
    Bar() = default;

public:
    static auto Create() {        
        return std::make_shared<Bar>(Foo());
    }  
    explicit Bar(Foo);    
};

int main()
{
    auto i = Bar::Create();
}
```

See [**DEMO**](https://godbolt.org/z/OlDEwD).

You can adapt the above to your requirement.

Comment: @M.M I don't think so, pretty sure `make_shared` will pass construction onto some allocation function that we don't know about (and likely isn't portable to friend even if we did know about it).

Comment: Could not make `std::make_shared` a `friend` but found a hack that will allow the use of `make_shared` with a `private` constructor.

Answer (score 13):

Because it is the library function `std::make_shared` that is invoking private constructor.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using the `empty private class constructor argument` hack, then you can just construct the `shared_ptr` from a raw ptr:

```
#include <memory>
class Bar
{
private:
  Bar() = default;
public:
  static std::shared_ptr<Bar> Create() {
    return std::shared_ptr<Bar>(new Bar);
  };
};
```